# VSTO Word Add-Ins No Longer Run Successfully

Tags: .net, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I have multiple Word add-ins that have been installed and successfully ran in the past but now using those same installation files, they have encountered the same runtime errors.

As a control test, I created a new project with the Word VSTO Add-in template (.Net 4.8, Any CPU, Word 2304, Visual Studio 17.7.6) and here's error log when attempting to run it in debug:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.


************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/jzhou/source/repos/WordAddIn1/WordAddIn1/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/jzhou/source/repos/WordAddIn1/WordAddIn1/bin/Debug/WordAddIn1.DLL.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070002). Probing terminated.

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.CreateEntryPoint(String entryPointTypeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.LoadEntryPoints(IntPtr serviceProvider)




************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Deployment
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.9037.0 built by: NET481REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Tools
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Implementation
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Implementation/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Implementation.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60910.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.dll
----------------------------------------
```

This issue has ocurred in all projects that I have attempted to debug. It has also occurred when I install published builds.

Things that have been tried and failed to produce a functioning add-in:

- Rebuilding the solution
- Rebuilding on a co-worker's machine
- Using a new VM, reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 and VSTO.
- Installing the add-in in different versions of Word (2304, 2208, 2102, 64-bit, 32-bit) and across different computers.
- Changing the self-signed coding certificate

The only thing that appears to work is installing the add-in in VDI (Word version 2022) but due to the nature of VDI it gets wiped away after a user logs off. Also, users who had their add-ins installed before this issue cropped up don't see any problems. This issue only occurs for new installs.

My suspicion is something changed in the environment.

Comment: So I installed Word (2310) on my home personal computer and got the add-ins running successfully. This definitely leads me to believe that there's something wrong with the desktop environment at work. Could something like a GPO policy cause this?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like what happened was our Sysmon was blocking the dlls.